# Vuejs does not work well in a view of laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I'm trying to use vuejs directly in a view of the room but I can't get it to work. Attached code

Prueba.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div id="demox">
    <h1>Pruebas</h1>
    <h3 v-text="title"></h3>
</div>


@endsection

@section('scripts')

<script>

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    const demo = new Vue({
        el: '#demox',
        data:function(){
            return {
                title: "Titulo en VUEJS"
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            console.log('cargado')
        },
    })
  });

</script>

@endsection
```

Layout.app.blade.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito" rel="stylesheet">

    @yield('styles')
    <!-- Styles -->
    <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-success shadow-sm">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="navbar-brand text-white" href="{{ url('/') }}">
                    {{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}
                </a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="{{ __('Toggle navigation') }}">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                    <!-- Left Side Of Navbar -->
                    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">

                    </ul>

                    <!-- Right Side Of Navbar -->
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                        <!-- Authentication Links -->
                        @guest
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('login') }}">{{ __('Login') }}</a>
                            </li>
                            @if (Route::has('register'))
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('register') }}">{{ __('Register') }}</a>
                                </li>
                            @endif
                        @else
                            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                                <a id="navbarDropdown" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" v-pre>
                                    {{ Auth::user()->name }} <span class="caret"></span>
                                </a>

                                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('logout') }}"
                                       onclick="event.preventDefault();
                                                     document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
                                        {{ __('Logout') }}
                                    </a>

                                    <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
                                        @csrf
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        @endguest
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="py-4 mt-1 col-12">
                    @yield('botones')
                </div>
                <main class="py-4 mt-2 col-12">
                    @yield('content')
                </main>
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    @yield('scripts')

</body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
/**
 * First we will load all of this project's JavaScript dependencies which
 * includes Vue and other libraries. It is a great starting point when
 * building robust, powerful web applications using Vue and Laravel.
 */
import VueSweetalert2 from 'vue-sweetalert2';


require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

/**
 * The following block of code may be used to automatically register your
 * Vue components. It will recursively scan this directory for the Vue
 * components and automatically register them with their "basename".
 *
 * Eg. ./components/ExampleComponent.vue -> <example-component></example-component>
 */

// const files = require.context('./', true, /\.vue$/i)
// files.keys().map(key => Vue.component(key.split('/').pop().split('.')[0], files(key).default))
Vue.use(VueSweetalert2);
Vue.component('example-component', require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue').default);
Vue.component('eliminar-registro', require('./components/EliminarRegistro.vue').default);
Vue.component('modal-encuestas', require('./components/ModalEncuestas.vue').default);
Vue.component('abrir-modal', require('./components/AbrirModal.vue').default);
Vue.component('ejemplo-prueba', require('./components/EjemploPrueba.vue').default);


/**
 * Next, we will create a fresh Vue application instance and attach it to
 * the page. Then, you may begin adding components to this application
 * or customize the JavaScript scaffolding to fit your unique needs.
 */

// const app = new Vue({
//     el: '#app',
// });
```

Errors:

app.js:42027 [Vue warn]: The "data" option should be a function that returns a per-instance value in component definitions.

app.js:42027 [Vue warn]: Property or method "title" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property. See: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.**

What could be happening? Thank you

Comment: The error `app.js:42027 [Vue warn]: The "data" option should be a function that returns a per-instance value in component definitions.` doesn't seem related to your current code, so I suspect it's from a previous run. Please refresh the page and check again for errors.

Comment: Yes, indeed yesterday the code was working, I made some changes and it stopped working. I have updated the browser, cleaned caches, etc but it still doesn't work. Any other ideas?

Comment: The funny thing is that the console.log of the mounted() executes it correctly

Comment: Has the error changed?

Comment: yes, on some occasions the code does not recognize VUEJS (Vue is not defined) it is for that reason that I have added the DOMCONTENTLoaded. Now the code recognizes VUE but does not work properly

Yesterday what happened is that I created new components and then deleted them because I didn't use them. Now I don't use them but since then VUEJS doesn't work properly. Can it be related? I edit the publication and add the app.js file